# Define custom command-line parameters in C?

Tags: c, terminal, command-line-arguments

I need to pass a 'key' as a parameter from terminal. It should run as 
 **`./a.out -k100101001`** 
where 10011001 is the key and `-k` is the flag to specify it.
If I need to pass a filename along with the key it should run as 
**`./a.out -k10011001 -iparameter.txt`** 
 where parameter.txt is the filename and -i is the flag to specify that.

**NOTE:** I have several parameters to pass and parameter values are followed after the flag without space(-iparameter.txt), plus I don't know the order of the flags so doing something like this won't help.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
if (argc == 2) {
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-k")) something();
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-i")) something();
}
```

Any suggestion for C? I'm using Ubuntu to run my program.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using a loop through argv should do it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numArg;

    for (numArg = 1; numArg < argc; numArg++)
    {
        if (argv[numArg][0] == '-')
        {
            switch (argv[numArg][1])
            {
            case 'k' : somethingAboutKey(argv[numArg] + 2); // The parameter's value is passed directly to the function
                       break;
            case 'i' : somethingAboutFile(argv[numArg] + 2);
                       break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Such ad hoc argument parsing loops lead to ad hoc command line syntaxes. It is far better to use `getopt()` (or `getopt_long()`) or an equivalent to parse arguments.